# Is there an action to track down the previous screen and use it to change something in another screen?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, ibaction, mkpinannotationview

Is there an action like:

```
if (previous_view.title = @"newyork")
{
mapPin.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
}

if (previous_view.title = @"washington")
{
mapPin.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;
}
```

I am creating an app where there is a map, and if you click a pin's annotation, it leads to a screen that has the button map, and if I click that, then the pin needs to change to a different color, and I was wondering if there is such an action that would be based on the name or any other attributes of the previous view (where it came from).

Here is the code I use to go to the next screen after I press the annotation:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
if ([view.annotation.title isEqual: @"New York"])
    {
    newyork *controller1 = [[[newyork alloc] initWithNibName:@"newyork" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    controller1.delegate = self;
    controller1.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentViewController:controller1 animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

And this is the code inside the newyork.m file that is the action to what happens when the map button is pressed:

```
- (IBAction)mapPressed:(id)sender
{
map *controller1 = [[[map alloc] initWithNibName:@"map" bundle:nil] autorelease];
controller1.delegate = self;
controller1.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentViewController:controller1 animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

I really need help with this!!
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This question is very confusing. What does the posted (invalid) code have to do with the very unclear question? What do you mean by "action"?

Comment: I think you want to loop through the subviews of your current UIView's superview... or something like that?

Comment: Have you written the code that responds to the annotation click and shows the screen with the button?  Maybe posting that code will help your question.  If you haven't written the annotation-click-handling code yet, solve that before going further.

Comment: In mapPressed, are you sure you want to create a new map vc?  Don't you want to call dismissViewControllerAnimated instead so it goes back to the map vc it came from?

Comment: I could do that as well, but I didn't think it mattered. I would do it if it would be easier to change the pin color that way.

Answer (score 3):

I assume by "view" you mean "view controller".

After that assumption. Yes you can check this if you are using UINavigationController and push view controller over that navigation controller. To do so:

```
UIViewController *previousController = [self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:self.navigationController.viewControllers.count - 2];

if ([previousController.title isEqual:@"something"]) {
    // Do Something
}
```

Bu this is not the suggested approach. You should not depend your navigation controller stack for conditional actions on you view controller. You should pass this parameters to your view controller, preferably on initialisation. Like:

```
[[SomeViewContoller alloc] initWithStateName:stateName];
```

Comment: What if the view where the map is is called UIViewController, and there is just an MKMapView inside it?

Comment: Is there something like the first piece of code you gave, but not for navigation controllers, because I don't use them.

Answer (score 1):

`MKAnnotationView` Class Reference

> Annotation views support the concept of a selection state, which determines whether the view is unselected, selected, or selected and displaying a standard callout view. The user toggles between the selection states through interactions with the annotation view. In the unselected state, the annotation view is displayed but not highlighted. In the selected state, the annotation is highlighted but the callout is not displayed. And finally, the annotation can be displayed both with a highlight and a callout. The callout view displays additional information such as a title string and controls for viewing more information. The title information is provided by the annotation object but your annotation view is responsible for providing any custom controls. For more information, see the subclassing notes.

So what u can do is subclass an `MKAnnotationView` and override the `-(void)setSelected:animated:` method.